# Android - Make user connect to the internet

Tags: android

In my Android application, I have a logon task in the opening of the app that needs internet connection to get some data, I'm able to test if there's an internet connection thanks to the `ConnectivityManager` class, but I also want to make the user, or at least suggest him to connect to the internet. Is there any way I can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an alert that says they must connect to interenet for application to run. Then open the wireless settings on button select

```
public static void showNoConnectionDialog(Context _context) {
        final Context context = _context;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setMessage("WiFi Connection is needed for app to run");
        builder.setTitle("Not Connected to WiFi");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Connect", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               //Close out of app or something
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can launch an intent to go to the device's settings with:

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

You can find other similar Intent actions in the [`android.provider.Settings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) class.